# What would be the most ideal rotation for frost mage pvp?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I know in pvp situations change drastically on certain factors so we wont start a discussion on how to be a better pvper. But something that would give me a better idea of what I should be focused on while pvping would be, in the most ideal situation what would be the best rotation for a frost mage. Basically all cool downs are ready to go, enemy player hasn't seen you yet and there are no other enemies around to bother you.

My current rotation is basically pet nova, frostbolt/ice lance, frostbolt/ice lance, blink if they have gained ground, more frostbolt.

I don't seem to be able to nuke down them fast enough compared to other players I have watched.

I'm looking for the most ideal rotation for nuking down players.

Comment: I would say there is no rotation for PvP, rather you should look at a desission tree or prioritization solution, PvP is allot more about reacting to what the enemy is doing or have done(what abilitys are on cooldown) rather than just following a rotation

Comment: That part of pvp I understand; when to sheep, when to counterspell, when to blink, ect. The trouble I'm having is actually nuking down a target once the opportunity arises.

Comment: @Blem: I think your comment should be the answer, because I was going to post exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's also going to depend on the class that you're attacking. Personally, I wouldn't start with the pet nova just b/c I always use that as a good "oh s!@#" button mid-fight (at least against melee - vs casters I wouldn't bother unless I had a melee ally trying to beat his face in - and really only if it's an aff lock).

I think another thing to keep in mind is that frost mages aren't "nukers" - they're kiters. In a race against another caster though, depending on spec & gear it could be a number of different things -- my suggestion is to hit up a training dummy and feel out your toon. I look at my shaman as a perfect example of the difference in play style you get outta gear: before I had spell haste I needed ghost wolf and grounding totem, after I had haste I needed grounding totem =]

At the end of the day, I'd say before learning how to dps as a frost mage, learn how to escape and evade. Frost mages are KING at that. You learn that, you won't have to deal crazy dmg to come out the victor.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would say there is no rotation for PvP, rather you should look at a decision tree or prioritization solution, PvP is a lot more about reacting to what the enemy is doing or has done (what abilities are on cooldown) rather than just following a rotation.

That being said you should focus on getting casts off while your target can't interrupt you, even though ice lance is instant cast it still results in a global CD, so unless your target is frozen I would say cast a frost bolt rather than an ice lance if you can.

Also the example you gave you should use the moment of surprise to your advantage. Your target in the scenario you described won't see you coming so you can get the first frost bolt off before he starts to reacts and start casting a 2nd before he will move, at this time you should use your pet's frost nova.

I know [Cartoonz](http://www.youtube.com/user/Hogmanlolz) has made some pvp tutorial videos, there might be something you can use. He is fire at some point, but his earlier videos (from start of cata) are about frost.

Disclaimer: It has been a while since I played wow and also a long time since I played my mage as frost.